# Not able to use curl on HDInsight cluster

Tags: powershell, curl, azure-hdinsight

I'm attempting to run a spark job on HDInsight cluster with curl.

curl -k --user "admin:password" -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{ "file":"https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/spark-container/sparkjob-jar-with-dependencies.jar", "className":"io.spark.Driver" }' "https://cluster-spark.azurehdinsight.net/livy/batches"

error:
Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type 
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".

Comment: What operating system are you using?